# Transform json by filtering array of objects and show single element

Tags: jolt

I am trying to transform using JOLT.

Below are my input, expected and spec. How do I show only currency without curly brackets?

> Input

```
{
  "txn": [
    {
      "direction": "BUY",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    {
      "direction": "SELL",
      "currency": "EUR"
    }
  ]
}
```

> Specification

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "txn": {
        "*": {
          "direction": {
            "BUY": {
              "@2": "buyCurrency"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

> Expected output

```
{
  "buyCurrency" : "USD"
}
```

> Current output

```
{
  "buyCurrency" : {
    "direction" : "BUY",
    "currency" : "USD"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "txn": {
        "*": {
          "direction": {
            "BUY": {
              "@2": "."
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "direction": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "currency": "currency"
    }
  }
]
```